# if (!isset($_SESSION['adminid'])) { Stops page from loading

Tags: php

```
<?php

if (!isset($_SESSION['adminid'])) { 
    exit();
}
?>
```

Stops the page from loading when I delete it I can load the page. Anyone knows what the problem is? Yes I am very bad at coding.

Edit:

```
<?php

if (!isset($_SESSION['adminid'])) { 
    if (isset($_GET['forgot'])) { ?>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <div class="formularzowyNaglowek">Account Email Address:</div>
        <input type="email" name="mail" placeholder="Email address" required>
        <input type="submit" name="forgotBtn" value="Reset">
    </form> 

<?php } else if (isset($_GET['r'])) { ?>
```

Edit 2: All I can could find was:

```
if (password_verify($pass, $p)) {
            $_SESSION['adminid'] = $uid;
             exit();


if (!isset($_SESSION['adminid'])) { 
    header('Location: /admin/login');
} else {
```

Edit 3:

```
<?php
require_once('../config.php');
require_once('../php/functions.php');

?>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="eng">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>Admin Panel</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<?php

if (isset($_POST['loginBtn'])) {
    $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['mail']);
    $pass = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);


    $sql = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM admin WHERE email = ?');
    $sql->bind_param('s', $email);
    $sql->execute();
    $result = $sql->get_result();

    if ($result->num_rows < 1) {
        echo "<h1>Wrong email or password</h1>";
    } else {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $p = $row['password'];
            $uid = $row['id'];
        }

        if (password_verify($pass, $p)) {
            $_SESSION['adminid'] = $uid;
             exit();

        } else {
            echo "<h1>Wrong email or password 2</h1>";
        }
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['forgotBtn'])) {
    $code = randomChars(20);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['mail']);

    $sql = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM admin WHERE email = ?');
    $sql->bind_param('s', $email);
    $sql->execute();

    $result = $sql->get_result();

    if ($result->num_rows < 1) {
        echo "<h1>No user with that email</h1>";
    } else {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $uid = $row['id'];
        }
        $sql = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO resetpass (userID, code) VALUES (?, ?)');
        $sql->bind_param('ss', $uid, $code);
        $sql->execute();

        $message = "Your reset link: " . "http://" .$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/admin/login?r=' . $code;
        $to = $email;
        $title = "Reset Password";
        if (sendEmail($to, $message, $title)) {
            echo "Email with reset code has been sent";
        } else {
            echo "Error while sending email";
        }
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['resetBtn'])) {
    $nPass = htmlspecialchars($_POST['nPass']);
    $code = $_POST['code'];

    $password = password_hash($nPass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    $sql = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM resetpass WHERE code = ?');
    $sql->bind_param('s', $code);
    $sql->execute();

    $result = $sql->get_result();

    if ($result->num_rows < 1) {
        echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
    } else {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $uid = $row['userID'];
        }
        $sql = $conn->prepare('UPDATE resetpass SET used = "1" WHERE code = ?');
        $sql->bind_param('s', $code);
        $sql->execute();

        $sql = $conn->prepare('UPDATE admin SET password = ? WHERE id = ?');
        $sql->bind_param('ss', $password, $uid);
        $sql->execute();

        echo "Password changed successfuly, you can now login";
    }
}




?>
<?php

if (!isset($_SESSION['adminid'])) { 
    exit();
}
?>
<?php

if (!isset($_SESSION['adminid'])) { 
    if (isset($_GET['forgot'])) { ?>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <div class="formularzowyNaglowek">Account Email Address:</div>
        <input type="email" name="mail" placeholder="Email address" required>
        <input type="submit" name="forgotBtn" value="Reset">
    </form> 

<?php } else if (isset($_GET['r'])) { ?>

    <form action="" method="POST">
        <div class="formularzowyNaglowek">New Password:</div>
        <input type="password" name="nPass" placeholder="New password" required>
        <input type="hidden" name="code" value="<?php echo $_GET['r'] ?>" required>
        <input type="submit" name="resetBtn" value="Reset">
    </form> 

<?php
    } else { ?>
        <h2 style="text-align: left;">Login to admin panel</h2>
        <form action="" method="POST">
        <div class="formularzowyNaglowek">Email Address:</div>
        <input type="email" name="mail" placeholder="Email address" required>
        <div class="formularzowyNaglowek">Password:</div>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
        <input type="submit" name="loginBtn" value="Login">
        </form> 
        <a href="/admin/login?forgot">Forgot your password?</a>
<?php
    }
} else {

}





?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `var_dump($_SESSION);` what does it return? Did you start the session first, using `session_start()`?

Comment: It outputs: array(0) { } @Qirel EDIT: And yes I did start the session somehow it just doesnt continue

Comment: Can you show us the code where you populate the session variable?

Comment: @Dharman I think you mean this? In my admin panel index: require_once('../config.php'); And in my config: <?php
session_start();

The rest is my database + pass etc

Comment: I mean where do you fill `$_SESSION['adminid']`?

Comment: Do you have `session_start()` on that page? You need to start the session on each page that is going to use the session variable.

Comment: My friend made this years ago so I am not quite sure but I think you mean this.



It's in admin/login.php

Comment: @Qirel I start session in config.php wich it requires once should I remove it from config.php and add it into the index.php?

Comment: Please add the code from login.php in the question, not in the comments.

Comment: @Dharman done :)

Comment: Is that all, I still don't see any assignments to `$_SESSION['adminid']`

Comment: @Dharman Added everything I could fine

Comment: `if (!isset($_SESSION['adminid'])) { exit(); }` when added at the top of the file will make sure that this file is executed only after the user is logged in. Are you sure that you are logged in when you execute that file?

Comment: @Dharman I think that would be the problem. Added my login.php to the question.

Comment: I do not understand why you have added `if (!isset($_SESSION['adminid'])) { exit(); }`, it makes no sense to me

Comment: @Dharman If I don't add it it goes straight trough without giving chance to log in and with it shows a blank page xd So idk what to do anymore.